# Convert SQLite database to JSON in Haskell

Tags: json, sqlite, haskell

Is there any way to dump a SQLite database into a JSON file in Haskell? All other questions are parsing json and saving to sqlite. I can't seem to find any reference on this, please help me.

I created a simple haskell app using stack that pulls details about movies from a HTML web source by applying haskell functions and then save the data into a SQLite database file. The purpose of the app is to allow users to query the database. The database consists of 1 table called "movies".

I want to write a module that generates a JSON representation of my Haskell data to dump the SQLite database into a JSON file.

SQLite table:

---

rank | name | director | year | rating | starring |

---

This is what I have managed to come up with so far. This creates a JSON file with a single record.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I
import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON)
-- Custom Datatype
data Movie = Movie {
      rank :: Int,          
      name :: String,       
      director :: String,   
      year :: Int,          
      rating :: Double,     
      starring :: String    
      } deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON) 

convertToJson = Movie { rank = 125, name = "Puzzle", director = "Marc Turtletaub", year = 2018 , rating = 83, starring = "Kelly Macdonald" }

main = I.writeFile "DB.json" (encodeToLazyText convertToJson)
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have code to read the SQLite database? When you have that, you can simply translate from the SQLite structure to `Movie` and write out the list of `Movie`s that you created.

Comment: Was the sqlite library you're using compiled with the JSON1 module enabled? That would make it easy to do purely in SQL.

Comment: Thank you 4castle I will edit my responses now.

Comment: Hi @Bob Dalgleish, I'm making use of simple SQL statements to query the database and display the results e.g. display movie by year.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Iam using Database.HDBC.Sqlite3.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.  You show code to write JSON, and say you have code to read `Movie` from the database.  What else is required?

Comment: @bergey Hi, I would like to convert my SQLite database table to JSON using a haskell function.

Comment: Does the **sqlite** library it's using come with the JSON1 extension compiled into it? The easy way to check is to see if `SELECT json('0')` works.

Comment: @user2023 your example already converts the record to JSON using a haskell function, so it's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @JeremyList Hi, I would like to be able to dump the database into JSON not just a single record.

Answer (score 1):

You never did answer my question about if the version of sqlite you're using has support for the JSON1 extension, so this pure-sql solution might not work for you, but if it does...

```
SELECT json_group_array(json_object('rank', rank
                                  , 'name', name
                                  , 'director', director
                                  , 'year', year
                                  , 'rating', rating
                                  , 'starring', starring))
FROM movies;
```

will return a string that is a JSON array with one JSON object per row of the table.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Im really sorry I forgot to answer your question. Thank you for taking the time for looking into this. Where do I check if JSON1 is supported? Do I need to write SELECT json('0') as part of a sql query?

Comment: could you please elaborate on where I place "json_group_array" statement within the context of my code above? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In Aeson you have this instance:

```
instance ToJSON a => ToJSON [a]
```

So you can just pass the entire list to `encodeToLazyText` and it will lazily create a JSON array.

For example:

```
main = I.writeFile "DB.json" (encodeToLazyText [convertToJson,convertToJson])
```

Comment: Hi @Jeremy List   do I have to write out the list of movies manually? Can I not write a sql query to get all the data from the table and then pass it to encodeToLazyText?

Comment: No, you just pass the list to `encodeToLazyText` and it will create a JSON array.